# Is there an option to convert to XSLT view for Calendar Webpart?

Tags: web-part, xslt, calendar, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am trying to modify the calendar view of a document library. However, there doesnt seem to be an option for showing the name of the document on the calendar. I would like to have users click on the URL on the calendar and have them taken directly to the document. Instead, the item view window pops up.

One way around this, I thought, was to to convert the webpart to xslt view and update the title reference to fileleaf reference. But it doesnt seem like you can convert the calendar webpart to xslt view webpart. Is there a way to do this?

Please help. Thanks in advance!